# How to make my ASP.net web application know what time it is at the user's location?

Tags: asp.net, time, timezone

I'm working on a web application that keeps track of scheduling for my organization.  There are over 100 different official locations that it can be used from.  When a user logs in, the user's physical location is saved in the session.

There is a button on the application that the user can click on.  I have a requirement that when the user clicks the button, the application must record what time it is at the user's physical location.

I'm aware that it may have made sense to design the application to instead use UTC internally, but the program has been using local time for years.  However, thus far, I can't see that anyone ever did anything that required use of the current time (other than the date).

I can see in my database that each location has a "locale ID" that should correspond to a time-zone, but I know that there are differences in how "daylight savings time" and "summer time" are taken into account around the world.

What's an efficient way of taking into account all these things so that when the user logs in at one of 100s of locations, I can tell what time it is at the user's physical location when he clicks a button?

Comment: You say you know the user's location.  What do you know about it?  Lat/lon cooridnates from a phone?  Some physical data from the way the were established in your application?  To do timezone conversions, you will need some timezone information from either `TimeZoneInfo` class in .Net, or a TZDB implemenation like [NodaTime](https://code.google.com/p/noda-time/).  The only question is how you determine the user's timezone.

Comment: you can save seperate table for timezones...as you have timezones for each user....you can easily find their time....using offset of timezone...just add the offeset to your server time..

Comment: @Daniel - If you reliably know the location, you can either pre-set or determine the time zone.  Then you're in business.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have this figured out.  I was able to verify this solution with at least one location I've tested so far.

The "Local IDs" that I referred to are the same strings that you can pass into various .net time zone functions such as `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId`.  This function seems to be sufficient to get the local time at the user's location.

It's a good point that some of you brought up in the comments, about how a user's motivation to cheat the system might come into play, but I believe that my solution works regardless.

Comment: Ah - I misunderstood.  You said "locale", so I thought you meant something like `en-US`.  Yes - if you have an actual Windows time zone id for each user, then you can simply use the `TimeZoneInfo` class to do your conversions.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to guarantee that it's right, but you can retrieve the date and time the browser thinks it is by using javascript (by calling `new Date()`), then post that value using AJAX to the server - from there, do whatever you need to do.

There's a very good chance this date will be correct from the user's perspective.

Comment: Sorry Joe, but I couldn't disagree with you more.  You can never trust the user's clock.  You can try to detect the timezone with something like [jsTimeZoneDetect](https://bitbucket.org/pellepim/jstimezonedetect) and pair it with a TZDB implementation like [NodaTime](https://code.google.com/p/noda-time/), but even that is risky because you don't know that the user has set their timezone correctly.

Comment: That's probably going to be my fallback position if I can't figure anything else out, but I don't think my customer will like it!

Comment: @Joe - It would be great to chat if you can make it to [my talk at DCC](http://apr2013.desertcodecamp.com/session/630)

Comment: For the record, I said you won't be able to guarantee that it's right, and also that there's a very good chance it will be correct. Those are both true statements - there's no way to be sure what the user's date is, but since you're talking about business users, you can probably trust that your users have the right time on their machines, assuming your IT department knows what they're doing. And if it's wrong, they're only hurting themselves.

Comment: @MattJohnson With that said, I may stop by your session - dates are a pain in the neck, so I would be interested in seeing what kinds of solutions you've worked with.

Comment: When it comes to schedules and employees - people lie.  They go try devious things like changing their clocks and seeing if it gives them extra overtime or marks them on time when they came in late.  Trust me - this is one of the first things people will try.  :)

Comment: I suppose it depends on the audience at that point. If you're dealing with people punching a timeclock, that makes sense. If you're recording the time for their own benefit for scheduling meetings, posting to a forum, etc., they wouldn't have any incentive to cheat. A compromise might be to record both browser time and server UTC time, and use UTC for real purposes while letting the user see the browser time.

Comment: That's a fairly reasonable approach for some things - yes.

Comment: @Matt Johnson, it isn't a reasonable approach to track the time two different ways, IMO.  That's just adding an entirely unnecessary layer of complexity.

Comment: @DanielAllenLangdon - Agreed - I just meant, that if there was ambiguity of the location that you might partially trust your user to provide the zone - either from their clock or directly by asking them.